# how to fix " Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for install " error

Tags: python, pip, tweepy

I want to install tweepy module to my python project. I read in documentation to use command "pip install tweepy". But it shows up an error in command prompt.

```
C:\Python36>pip install tweepy
Collecting install
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for install
```

Edit-1

I tried to install python-twitter module and the same error shows up.

```
C:\Python36>pip install python-twitter -v
Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
Collecting install
  1 location(s) to search for versions of install:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/install/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/install/
  Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/simple/install/" in the cache
  Returning cached "301 Moved Permanently" response (ignoring date and etag information)
  Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/install/" in the cache
  Current age based on date: 345
  Freshness lifetime from max-age: 600
  Freshness lifetime from request max-age: 600
  The response is "fresh", returning cached response
  600 > 345
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.org/simple/install/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions: )
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for install
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MOJO-J~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplke7w3ae\pip.zip\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\MOJO-J~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplke7w3ae\pip.zip\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Users\MOJO-J~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplke7w3ae\pip.zip\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Users\MOJO-J~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplke7w3ae\pip.zip\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Users\MOJO-J~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplke7w3ae\pip.zip\pip\req\req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "C:\Users\MOJO-J~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplke7w3ae\pip.zip\pip\req\req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "C:\Users\MOJO-J~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplke7w3ae\pip.zip\pip\index.py", line 514, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
pip.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for install
```

Comment: For some reason it looks like your version of pip is trying to install "install" instead of "tweepy".

Comment: Only way I can simulate this is `pip install install tweepy`, where install was double typed or pasted twice.

Comment: no it doen't work. `C:\Python36>pip install install tweepy
Collecting install
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for install`

Comment: try to update your version of pip with `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: No, it shows same error `C:\Python36>pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting install
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement install (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for install`

Comment: So after a long time i found a way around. make a virual environment and do all work in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried different ways like `pip3 install tweepy` and `pip tweepy` like the solution advised above but that didn't work. Tried upgrading and reinstalling pip but still no solution. Had to do a whole reinstallation of python environment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have `pip` aliased to the `pip install` command for some reason.
You could probably just run `pip tweepy` to actually run `pip install tweepy`, but the better method would be to [run pip via the Python interpreter](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#running-pip). [Upgrading pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip) this way could also potenitally fix the aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing in lower version of python. Some libraries doesn't support a new version of python immediately.